Does every specialization of the HOMFLY polynomial produces a knot invariant polynomial?
It's a well known fact that the Alexander and Jones polynomials can be obtained as appropriate substitutions in the HOMFLY polynomial
$$V(t) = P(\alpha=t^{-1},z= t^{\frac{1}{2}}-t^{-\frac{-1}{2}}),$$
$$\Delta(t) = P(\alpha=1,z= t^{\frac{1}{2}}-t^{-\frac{-1}{2}}),$$
Where $V(t)$ and $\Delta(t)$ are the Jones and Alexander polynomials respectively and $P_{HOMFLY}(\alpha,z)$ denotes the HOMFLY polynomial.
$\textbf{Question:}$
Does every substitution $\alpha = f(t)$ and $z=g(t)$ in the HOMFLY polynomial produces a knot invariant polynomial in the variable $t$ $$P_{new}(t)=P_{HOMFLY}(\alpha=f(t),z=g(t)).$$
Thanks in advance!

Yes, because the HOMFLY polynomial is a knot invariant.
